# OpenLDAP, how to extend system schema

Tags: openldap

how can I extend system schema in openLDAP?
I have to migrate from OID(oracle internet directory) to openLDAP and I want to keep oracle specific attributes such orclaci. To be able to do so, I need to make top class know these attributes. 
Thank's a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

OpenLDAP contains a set of default schemas in it's distribution (see etc/openldap/schema), so you can edit or even replace any schema as you want.
I don't know OID specific, but guess that attributes like `orclaci` should be in separate schemas; in this case you should register that OID schema file(s) in your OpenLDAP to make it know specific attributes.